# How can I clear down a table if the user exits?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

So I have users who upload files for processing to my server. The contents are read to an SQL Table, call it ImportedData for all intents and purposes. The user then manipulates them, then when they want to submit the data for processing, the data is submitted to an upstream system (not important here) and then the data removed from said table.

However, there may be situations where the user does the import and then for whatever reason decide to navigate away from the page, close the browser and go home for the day, what have you. The impact is the rows will be left in ImportedData.

Now my initial thought is to just run an Agent job to remove any rows older than a day; it's unlikely a user will want to be able to process the data the morning after.

However, is there a "better" way?

The app is constructed using MVC ASP.Net Razor front end, all C# in the back end, Entity Framework, etc. I just wondered is there anything fancy I could do to remove the data from ImportedData specific to that import (unique GUID for that exact importing session) so when the user does any sort of unclean logout the data unique to that import is deleted?

Comment: Explaining with example each step of your process  will help a lot

Comment: Are you writing the contents to DB as they are being read by your backend?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to delete the rows directly. You could scheduled a job for a stored procedure, load the old data into a temp table and keep that until the next time the stored procedure get executed.

Logic will be:

```
Create procedure Name
AS
BEGIN
(
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME = N'...')
BEGIN
DROP TABLE ...
END
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME
...
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
SELECT ..
FROM YOUR_TABLE
)
END
```

Just make sure the data is kept incase some unwilling things happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thing you could potentially do: you could add a little javascript on the page in question that would do an ajax call to the server at a regular, reasonable interval - maybe once every few minutes - that would simply indicate to the server that the user's browser is still viewing that record.  You could update some sort of LastClientHeartbeat timestamp on the corresponding database record to indicate that it's still being viewed.  Then, in your regularly scheduled cleanup job, you could program it to skip deleting files whose LastClientHeartbeat timestamp is relatively recent (within the last few minutes), as this would indicate that the user still has that page open in the browser.

It's not a very sophisticated solution, but it would be pretty simple to implement, and it would (mostly) prevent you from accidentally deleting files that users were simply taking their sweet time to finish working on.